# .net object persistence

Tags: .net, object-persistence

Can you please suggest a free, open source or low cost `.net` object persistence framework? I am not looking for ORM tools like NHibernate or Entity Framework. The closest commercial product that describes my need is [fastobject.net](http://www.theserverside.net/news/thread.tss?thread_id=25578) framework. Thanks.

Comment: oh..sorry..I am new to SF. Thanks for reminding. Would remember in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try db4o at [www.db4o.com](http://www.db4o.com). It was recently acquired by Versant.

Some pro's:
It's open source with code available in java and c#. 
The framework is dead easy to use.
The community is quite nice and you can get answers quickly on the forums.

Comment: Between Karvonite and db4o, which one is better?

Comment: I'd say db4o is more mature but then again MS knows how to play catch-up. Db4o to me is easier to use as there's no need to build a persistence model and it knows how to deal with missing assemblies. I haven't seen any performance benchmarks that include both so hard to say which is faster. As a db4o MVP i favor db4o :)

Answer (score 5):

[Karvonite](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/karvonite). It promises to be simple and non-invasive, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: That's only hosted at Microsoft. It's not written by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I suppose it is MP Advanced Multimedia, but their website is only orange at the time...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CSLA.NET - http://lhotka.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/), goes not as deep as NHibernate does in the sense of being a 'real' ORM tool but when it comes to persistence it serves it's purpose very well.

Answer (score 0):

.Net SOP - Scalable Object Persistence (v4.5) is what you are looking for. Scalable, Stable and lightweight, low-memory req't and housed in a single DLL. It supports rock solid transaction (app crash, power-failure, etc... it will recover, rollback to previous committed state) and very scalable (100 million inserts in 2+ hrs using an avg laptop). It is Free, Open Source (LGPL 2.1 license) and Royalty Free redistribution, link: http://sop.codeplex.com.

This is the very 1st managed code achieving this performance + stability level. No comparison... you've got to read the product feature set and try it.